# How to disable text wrapping in text box control?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, word-wrap

I'm adding some text to the text box which is docked to window of 300x400 size. When I add some lengthily text I'm wrapping the text to the next line which makes my output look kind of bad looking.

How to prevent wrapping words in multiline text box?

I have tried having both horizontal and vertical scroll bars, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just set the `WordWrap` property to false.

Comment: Ah! I read the properties one time or another and I always miss some. Thanks.

Comment: I still get a wrap at 1024 characters. I don't see an obvious reason why... is that a hard cap?

Comment: No idea... you could probably find out if you look at the source code